# C# pass generic Form as parameter

Tags: c#, interface

I have several different forms, which all have a common method "refreshThisForm()". I created an interface

```
public interface IRefreshable
{
    void refreshThisForm(string[] data);
}
```

and made all those forms implement it. Then I wanted to use one method to refresh any of them

```
    private void refreshMyForm(IRefreshable openForm, string[] data)
    {
        if (openForm.InvokeRequired)
        {
            openForm.Invoke(new refreshMyFormDelegate(refreshMyForm), openForm, data);
        }
        else
        {
            openForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
            openForm.refreshThisForm(data);
            openForm.BringToFront();
            openForm.Focus();
        }
    }
```

which did not work, bacause it complained IRefreshable does not have InvokeRequired, Invoke, WindowsState, BringToFront, Focus. It seems silly to me to try and define all of them in the interface. Is there a simpler way to make this work?
Marek

Comment: Out of question boundaries but the approach seems to be wrong. If you are using WPF, you should be refreshing view model behind the UI and not the UI.

Comment: Perhaps make the method generic with a constraint - i.e. `private void refreshMyForm<TForm>(Form openForm, string[] data) where TForm : IRefreshable` - then you have access to the form, and you can cast it to access the `refreshThisForm` mrthod.

Comment: stuardt, if you meant something like this ```private void refreshMyForm<TForm>(Form myForm, string[] data) where TForm : IRefreshable { IRefreshable openForm = myForm as IRefreshable; if (openForm.InvokeRequired) ... ``` it odes not work. Complains as before

Comment: Add a [Read-only Property to your Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/interface-properties) that returns the Form.  Then you can retrieve it and call `InvokeRequired`?

Comment: when I declare all the methods and properties in the Interface, it works. But I was trying to avoid this ...

Comment: Don't declare all of those in the Interface!  Just declare ONE PROPERTY that returns the FORM itself.

Comment: @MarekPraski no I didn’t mean that, I was thinking more along the lines of only casting the form when you want to access the interface method, like `((IRefresha le)openForm).refreshThisForm(data);` - for the rest of the code, just use the form instance.

Answer (score 0):

NOt sure If I am connecting with your problem, but can you please try the bewlo code.

```
private void refreshMyForm(IRefreshable openForm, string[] data)
{
    openForm.refreshThisForm(data);
}
```

and use the above method by passign the concrete class object with data as parameter.

Comment: This will not work, because the forms are ALWAYS opened in another thread, so I need at least Invoke and InvokeRequired. Other than that, I do not see why this code you suggest should not work